Prevent getting a brighter image when using pdftk
I used pdftk to extract the first page with
pdftk A=input.pdf cat A1 output output.pdf

or
pdftk input.pdf burst

The first page contains an image. This gets brighter in the output pdf. What can I do to prevent this and ensure that the page stays the same?
I suspect that there are some metadata which are not properly transported over to the output pdf. But that is just me guessing.

Here is someone with seemingly a similar problem, but using a different tool: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45458409/1256347 Perhaps you can try other tools to reach the same goal and document what you've found so far in the question? That might help focus the search for a solution.

@SaaruLindestøkke: I am not sure, how to use the question/answers, which you linked to. Do you mean that I should change the color profile somehow? But how?

I don't know if the link provides a direct solution, but I thought it might give some paths to explore, i.e.: try out imagemagick, try out graphicsmagick with the options listed in the link, see if you can change the color mode from CMYK to RGB in your pdf before exporting with pdftk, etc...
Best is if you can [edit] your question describing your attempts, as that shows to others what you've tried and what didn't work, ensuring they won't suggest non-working solutions.
